# Polyline Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Can't figure out where my code is going wrong. Want markers on the map, when clicked on it indicates the City name. Want a line connecting the markers. Any ideas?

```
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.4519, -122.1519)
    ],
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 10,
map: map
});

var locations = [
  ['Dalian', 38.914003, 121.614682]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 5,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.141789, 124.825118),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    title: locations[i][0]
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are defining the polyline before you define the map. The `map` property of the polyline needs to be a valid map object, it is easier to do that if you define it after the map.
2. your polyline is in Palo Alto CA, the map is centered over China.
3. you only have one marker in your question, you can't make a polyline with one point.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2aj146da/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {

  var locations = [
    ['Dalian', 38.914003, 121.614682]
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.141789, 124.825118),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.4519, -122.1519)
    ],
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 10,
    map: map
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      title: locations[i][0]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```